# typo3_console throws error Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException - No such file

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Update of TYPO3 6.2 to TYPO3 8.7. 
After changing the sources i am able to start all update scripts in install tool as expected. But when i try to run them via typo3_console i get the following errors:

```
./typo3cms database:updateschema safe  

[ Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException ]
An exception occured in driver: No such file or directory 
caused by
[ Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException ]
No such file or directory
```

- installtool is working, no error there
- environment without errors
- flush cache in installtool works but  ./typo3cms cache:flush ends up in the same error messages.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was sitting in front of the screen.

I changed unintentionally the php version of cli from 7.2 to 7.0. typo3_console should work with 7.0 - it tests versions from 7.0 to 7.3 - so no error was thrown. But it doesn't: all errors are gone after switching to 7.2 back again.

Sorry for the noise ... perhaps it helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: even though typo3_console works with php 7.2, using composer you will get different symfony packages depending on the PHP version. this is the reason why you also must use the same PHP version in CLI.

Answer (score 4):

This error might also occur if your TYPO3 instance is running in a container (e.g. *ddev*) but you are trying to run your command from the host of the container.

So in case of ddev you have to run `ddev ssh` before trying to run a console command.

As you might have guessed: This happened to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the DB credentials based on the `TYPO3_CONTEXT`? then you need to set this also in CLI, e.g. using

```
TYPO3_CONTEXT=Production/Staging ./typo3cms <your command>
```

Comment: No, i don't ... and for tests i wrote the correct DB credentials in LocalConfiguration.php. Nothing changes.

Comment: I had the "same" error on a system where the context is switched. This answer solved my Problem. Thx Georg